# Create an array of array's of object from Nested Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

Suppose We have an Array with array of objects like

```
let array = [
[{value:'a',somepros:"old"}],
[{value:'d',somepros:"old"}],
[{value:'b',somepros:"old"}]
];
```

**And we have nestedObj like**

```
let obj ={
"a":{
"count":2
},
"b":{
"count":2
},
"c":{
"count":1
},
"e":{
"count":1
}
};
```

Now What I want is basically Using nested object i want to check the array's of object's array value if it exist or not and want to create an array as decleared above. Here the count in object is number no.of times the Array of object will appear in above array but. Suppose count is 2 for object proprerty "a" there is already an array of object exist having value "a". i want another array to be pushed number of time's the count but already exist 1 so 1 more time i will add it.
What I need is from Obj:

```
NewArr =[
[{value:'a',somepros:"old"}],
[{value:'a',somepros:"newpushed"}],
[{value:'b',somepros:"old"}],
[{value:'b',somepros:"newpushed"}],
[{value:'c',somepros:"newpushed"}],
[{value:'e',somepros:"newpushed"}],
];
```

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't really seems to make much sense in my opinion, but here it is:

```js
let array = [
  [{value:'a',somepros:"old"}],
  [{value:'d',somepros:"old"}],
  [{value:'b',somepros:"old"}]
],
obj ={
  "a":{
    "count":2
  },
  "b":{
    "count":2
  },
  "c":{
    "count":1
  },
  "e":{
    "count":1
  }
};

const res = [];
// loop each entry from obj.
for (const [key, {count}] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  // check whether the key exists in the original array.
    const matched = array.find((arr) => arr[0].value === key);
  // If it exists, push it.
  if (matched) res.push(matched);
  // then, add X elements "newpushed", where X is given by the count declared - 0 if matched doesn't exist, otherwise 1 (since an element already existed).
  res.push(
    ...Array.from({length: (count - (matched ? 1 : 0))}, (_) => ([{ value: key, somepros: 'newpushed' }]))
  );
}

console.log(res);
```

Comments in the snippet explains what is done.

Comment: I found your answer very useful. But I still have a problem because I am working with datasheet it requires data in the array of array's of object's format, which I already explained. The problem still persisting that If the previous I mean old array has data ``` [
  [{value:'a',somepros:"old"}],
  [{value:'a',somepros:"old2"}],
  [{value:'d',somepros:"old"}],
  [{value:'b',somepros:"old"}]
], ```
then what will be the solution for this?